# I want to start my game server at boot with screen, how?

Tags: screen, supervisord

I am using supervisor but I'm having a hard time of figuring out how to start screen along with a program. Basically it would be screen -S "servername" "command". Thats as basic as I can get, I also tried following the supervisor guide on where to add programs but I don't get which one is which. Help appreciated Thank you